# Attempted to call function "idn_to_ascii" from the global namespace when trying to use Mail methods in Prestashop

Tags: php, email, prestashop, intl

I am receiving a 500 internal error in Prestashop whenever it comes to using the inbuilt PHP `mail()` method. After enabling debug mode, I found that the cause is this:

> **(1/1) UndefinedFunctionException**
>
> Attempted to call function "idn_to_ascii" from the global namespace.
>
> *in Mail.php line 893*

I googled this issue as it is most probably common and was hit with a GitHub issue https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/issues/10640 which states that the `php-intl` extension is needed.

I SSH'd into my VPS and ran `sudo apt install php7.3-intl` since the PHP version I use is 7.3. This worked fine and installed the extension. However, after restarting the Apache2 service like so: `sudo systemctl restart apache2.service`. I am still hit with the same error message.

I have tried editing my `/etc/php/7.3/apache2/php.ini` fine to include the `extension=intl` on the autoloading but this did not fix my issue either.

Any information or help appreciated in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After following some advice on another forum, I created a blank file and outputted the `phpinfo()` to see which PHP ini was default loading since my Server has PHP5 on it.

This told me that the `php5` ini was being used.

To change this to my PHP7.3, I did this:

```
sudo a2dismod php5
sudo a2enmod php7.3
```

This fixed my issues.